# simple Program to access digitalocean droplet information in java

Tags: java, digital-ocean

I am new to DigitalOcean.I would like to run basic java program to access DigitalOcean droplet. please let me know step by step procedure.

Comment: What is the need to access droplet through Java Code when they have already provide web interface or you can use different other tools ?

Comment: @askkuber because OP is a Programmer

Comment: i am new to this concept and don't know about any kind of tool. what kind of web interface may i use? i didn't get perfect tutorial for digitalocean java API? can u suggest me a link to know more about how can i access droplets using java API?

Comment: I think already answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about your droplets using their official API. It is a simple REST api which you can call using Java's `URL` class.

More about howto make HTTP GET using Java:

[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

For simple retrieval of information about your account, Droplets etc. you should use the `GET` method. The information you request will be returned to you as a JSON object. You can find numerous JSON libraries for Java (e.g. [json.org/java](http://www.json.org/java/)).

### API docs

Documentation of DigitalOcean API:

https://developers.digitalocean.com/

Documention section related to Droplets:

https://developers.digitalocean.com/#droplets

List of all Droplets:

https://developers.digitalocean.com/#list-all-droplets

Retrieve an existing Droplet by id:

https://developers.digitalocean.com/#retrieve-an-existing-droplet-by-id