# Access Droplet of DigitalOcean Using Java API

Tags: java, digital-ocean

I am New to Digital Ocean.i searched everywhere but didn't get exact tutorial to access droplet using java API.i would like to know what are the dependency should i add? what packages should i import? how can i write java program to access droplet. My project is in maven.

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple Program to access digitalocean droplet information in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739119/simple-program-to-access-digitalocean-droplet-information-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this API client in Java](https://github.com/jeevatkm/digitalocean-api-java) might be what you're looking for. From their readme, for use with Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myjeeva.digitalocean</groupId>
    <artifactId>digitalocean-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```